# Dynamic desktop push notifications - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, push-notification, html5-notifications

For send desktop notifications I use this code. (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification)

```
<button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button>

function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
```

This will work on same page when I press button, but what should I do if I want to manage these notifications dynamically ?
i.e. If I push notification from backend (admin) it should show message to front-end (users' who allow notifications)

Comment: This is a bit tricky, are you on iis or apache?

Comment: Apache, i think rest api will help here. But i am new n not sure

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps

1. **Have a function {notifyMe(msg)} in user end.**
   In Javascript define a function as like in question notifyMe();
2. **send an ajax call in a particular interval to check admin status for the current logged user**
   Send an ajax call to the server in a particular interval. Call Ajax inside  setInterval function and send request for every 20Sec.
3. **If admin status is set with message or a flag, Pass the message to your defined function {notifyMe(msg)}. User will be noticed automatically.**
   In server side script check if the notification is enabled for the user (say for user id 10) by administrator. If it is set to enabled (user id 10) in serverside, then in ajax return call your function **notifyMe()**. Once you determine to stop the notification clear the interval in javascript.

You may get the user id in server side script either from session or a parameter from Ajax call. So based on the user id you will perform whether to call or not to call Ajax and **notifyMe()**

Comment: Can u please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @Rijo Updated my answer